# Throwing basketballs to propel a car

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, forces

**Problem:**

For some odd reason, you decide to throw baseballs at a car of mass M, which is free to move frictionlessly on the ground. You throw the balls at the back of the car at speed u, and at a mass rate of σ kg/s (assume the rate is continuous, for simplicity). If the car starts at rest, find its speed and position as a function of time, assuming that the back window is open, so that the balls collect inside the car.

---

We suppose a zero net external force on the system consisting of the car+stream of basketballs. We treat the problem as if everything takes place in one dimmension. We have then from the formula for a variable mass system:

$v_{rel}*m'=mv'$

where $m$ is the mass of the car, $v$ is the velocity of the car, and $v_{rel}=u-v$ is the relative speed of the basketballs w.r.t the car.

Everything is fine so far, but my next step was to assume that $m'=\sigma$. Apparently this is false, and we actually have $m'=\sigma(u-v)/u$, but I don't understand why?

Of course after we setup the differential equation the rest is not interesting...

Comment: What is $m'$ here?

Comment: The variable mass system equation is essentially $F=\frac{d(mv)}{dt}$ but there is no F in your equation. Have you assumed it to be zero for some reason? 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-mass_system

Comment: @WojciechMorawiec : $m'$ is the derivative of m with respect to time.

Comment: @JMLCarter : as I noted in the question details, we suppose the net external force is zero, which is indeed a valid assumption is it not?

Answer (score 1):

Think of a cylinder of length $u\Delta t$ which has a mass of baseballs $\sigma \Delta t$ within it.
This will represent the mass of baseballs $\sigma \Delta t$ hitting a stationary target in a time $\Delta t$.

However the car is moving away from the baseballs at a speed $v$ so now the length of the cylinder of baseballs which hit the car in a time $\Delta t$  is $(u-v)\Delta t$.
If the rate of mass of baseballs hitting the car is $\dot m$ then  $\dfrac{\dot m \Delta t}{\sigma \Delta t}=\dfrac{(u-v)\Delta t}{u\Delta t}$ and the required equation for $\dot m$ follows.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why the last equation is true. I still don't understand: if by definition we throw $\sigma$ kg/s of basketballs, then it intuitively the speed of the car should be irrelevant because $\sigma$ kg/s must of basketballs must hit the back of the car.

Comment: Imagine the car travelling as fast as the basketballs then how many hit the car?  If the car was moving towards the basketball more would hit the car.  So the speed of the car is important.

Comment: of course you are right, my intuition was wrong!

Comment: but I still don't understand where the last equation that you wrote comes  from...

Answer (score 0):

you could solve it better by conservation of momentum.

lets suppose at time t the total mass added would be 
$\sigma t$.

so initial momentum of car is zero. and of masses is
$u\sigma t$

let velocity of system afterwards is v
so $$u\sigma t=(M+\sigma t)v$$
$$v=\frac{u\sigma t}{M+\sigma t}$$.

and position $$x=\int vdt$$

Comment: This is what I did, but it gives the wrong answer, because as I said the total mass added is NOT $\sigma t$

Comment: @JoshuaBenabou why is it not $\sigma t$?

Comment: ATHARVA: in case you didn't notice, that is exactly my question...

Comment: @JoshuaBenabou Do you know right answer? I do not fell any reason for that being wrong.

Comment: its simple math mass=rate*time

Comment: Once again the correct expression for $\sigma$ is posted in the question details... I too don't understand why its not correct...

Comment: it will not be $\sigma t$ only is $\sigma$ varies with time.

Comment: how did you found out that $$m'=\frac{\sigma (u-v)}{u}$$